# Add message to existing NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, throwable

I'm catching different kind of Exceptions in my method.

If the exception is a `NullPointerException`, I'd like to add a message to the existing exception.

Is there a way to add a message to an existing NullPointerException? I can't just create a new Exception, because I need the stacktrace etc.

My idea was to just create a new Exception like that:

```
new Exception("the message", myNullPointer);
```

But then, the output isn't as I need it, because that way, my stacktrace looks like that:

```
java.lang.Exception:
...bla
...bla
```

But I need it to keep the NullPointerException like that:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:
...bla
...bla
```

Also it's important to say that I haven't access to the part where the initial NullPointer is created. So I can't add a message at start.

**Edit:** I know I should avoid NPEs. But I have to influence about the thrown NPE. So I have to react.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't it a good idea to make sure that there are no NPE's by doing a simple null check...

Comment: Wrap it.  RuntimeException is good for this - is unchecked and has a cause exception in the constructor.  Unwrap it with getCause() later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this may not be a good idea, especially because null exception might arise out of situations you didn't expect.

Nevertheless, you can do exactly what you want like this:

```
try {
    ...potentially throws exceptions...
} catch (Exception e) {
    RuntimeException re = new RuntimeException(e);
    re.setStackTrace(e.getStackTrace());
    throw re;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to make some changes but your answer helped me to solve my problem. I just created a new NPE with the message and added the stacktrace from the existing NPE to the newly created one.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are looking at this:

```
public class NPException extends RuntimeException{

    public NPException(String message, Throwable exception){
        super(message, exception);
    }

}
```

then try with :

```
throw new NPException("TEsting..", new NullPointerException().getCause());
```

will give you something like:

> Exception in thread "main" NPException: TEsting..
>   at Test.main(Test.java:151)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure, passing your original exception in the constructor as you are suggesting is the best you can do. Optionally you can use `.getCause()` to determine the cause of the exception. That way you might be able to build a more meaningful output for yourself, e.g. logging it manually.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to call getCause() to retrieve your `NPE`

```
String nullString = null;
try {
  nullString.split("/");
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
  Exception ex = new Exception("Encapsulated", e);

  System.out.println("Direct Stacktrace");
  ex.printStackTrace();

  System.out.println("With getCause");
  ex.getCause().printStackTrace();
}
```